# Get the next record from Postresql view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a view **someView** according to my requirements

```
ID  |   name
3   |    A
4   |    F
8   |    G
13  |    E
26  |    Z
```

When I pass the ID in where condition I need to get the next record from the view
ie. If I pass 4 i should get back 8 . Also if I pass the last ID it should return the 1st record
ie. If I pass 26 i should get back 3.

I have been trying to use lag and lead but with nothing is working out.also I tried this

```
DECLARE aaa SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM someView where ID > someValue;
fetch 1 from aaa
```

In this case I do get the next value but It doesn't  get me results if I pass the last ID.
So what do I do about it?? Is there any other way that could solve my problem?

Comment: That's a real strange requirement.

Comment: I need to assign task. So when I get the ID of the last assigned person the task automatically gets assigned to the next person. And so  after it reaches the last person in the table it should go back to the 1st person. Now is that strange??

Comment: Ok. Is your `ID` column values are as shown in post? Or they are auto incremented?  just trying to confirm whether ID column value follows any pattern.

Comment: they are auto-incremented. But since it is a view , according to other requirements the ID may not be in ascending order. So here it does not follow any pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
with next_entry as (
   select *
   from sometable
   where id > 26 -- change the desired value here 
   order by id
   limit 1
)
select *
from next_entry
union all
select *
from sometable
where not exists (select 1 from next_entry)
limit 1;
```

It's probably not very efficient, but should work.

Comment: @a the query isnt working correctly. In random cases it gives wrong results like this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/32278/6

Comment: @Pradnya: sorry, I forgot the `order by` inside the CTE